# Benchmarks for Crate.io

Tags: benchmarking, crate

Are there any benchmarks for `Crate.io`?

I am particularly interested in storing a binary file (using shards and replicas of `Crate.io`) and to access it using the provided SQL similar language.

Comment: Would you mind updating the question from CREATE.IO to CRATE.IO?  Thanks!

Comment: cant edit anymore. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question.  Right now, we don't have any benchmarks available.  We've been planning to do some benchmarking although it's important to note that so many different factors can go into the results.  For example, cloud services are slower than bare metal, the configuration of the machine, the makeup of the data, the size of the cluster, the type of query...the list goes on and on.  So, if we're going to do benchmarks we want to make sure that we have the right setup and conditions.